# Setting navigation property doesn't set foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to seed a database with this code:

```
private static Contact ContactCreate(DbContext ctx, Company Company, string Description) {
    var contact = ctx.Contacts.Create();

    contact.Description = Description;

    contact.Company = Company;         // #1

    ctx.Contacts.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Description, contact);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    return ctx.Contacts.First(c=>c.Description == Description);
}
```

This fails when saving changes, because contact.CompanyId isn't set, and the foreign key constraint is not satisfied. If I change the line #1 tihe next line, the code executes right:

```
    contact.CompanyId = Company.Id;    // #2
```

Is this the usual behaviour?

Is needed the foreign key "CompanyId" when it has a navigation the property "Company"?

I think that are duplicates, because EntityFramework knows what is the key property in "Company" and should manage it for you.

EDIT:  This is the code generated from a model first approach

```
public partial class Contact : IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public partial class Company : IAuditable
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `Contact` class is defined?

Comment: Done... I'va added Company class too